# Is there a way to search for a string and copy text in front until it reaches a comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables, search

I am new to python and wanted to store the recentAveragePrice inside a variable (from a string like this one)

```
{"assetStock":null,"sales":250694,"numberRemaining":null,"recentAveragePrice":731,"originalPrice":null,"priceDataPoints":[{"value":661,"date":"2022-08-11T05:00:00Z"},{"value":592,"date":"2022-08-10T05:00:00Z"},{"value":443,"date":"2022-08-09T05:00:00Z"}],"volumeDataPoints":[{"value":155,"date":"2022-08-11T05:00:00Z"},{"value":4595,"date":"2022-08-10T05:00:00Z"},{"value":12675,"date":"2022-08-09T05:00:00Z"},{"value":22179,"date":"2022-08-08T05:00:00Z"},{"value":15181,"date":"2022-08-07T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14541,"date":"2022-08-06T05:00:00Z"},{"value":15310,"date":"2022-08-05T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14146,"date":"2022-08-04T05:00:00Z"},{"value":13083,"date":"2022-08-03T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14460,"date":"2022-08-02T05:00:00Z"},{"value":16809,"date":"2022-08-01T05:00:00Z"},{"value":17571,"date":"2022-07-31T05:00:00Z"},{"value":23907,"date":"2022-07-30T05:00:00Z"},{"value":39007,"date":"2022-07-29T05:00:00Z"},{"value":38823,"date":"2022-07-28T05:00:00Z"}]}
```

My current solution is this:

```
var = sampleStr[78] + sampleStr[79] + sampleStr[80]
```

It works for the current string but if the recentAveragePrice was above 999 it would stop working and i was wondering if instead of getting a fixed number i could search for it inside the string.

Comment: What is `sampleStr`?

Comment: Please share the full code you have tried with, otherwise we'll just be guessing.

Comment: Are you certain on dealing with a string rather than a dictionary?

Comment: Im having issues sharing the code but its in this replit page https://replit.com/@ShyMike/8-Bit-Collection-Profit#main.py

Comment: I recommend that you look at the *requests* module and, in particular, the json() function that's available in a requests.get() response object. That will give you a dictionary which will allow you straightforward access to the relevant key. Top tip: Don't try to process JSON as a string. Convert to a Python dictionary first. Rewrite as JSON if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replit code shows that you're acquiring JSON data from some website. Here's an example based on the URL that you're using. It shows how you check the response status, acquire the JSON data as a Python dictionary then print a value associated with a particular key. If the key is missing, it will print None:

```
import requests

(r := requests.get('https://economy.roblox.com/v1/assets/10159617728/resale-data')).raise_for_status()

jdata = r.json()

print(jdata.get('recentAveragePrice'))
```

**Output:**

```
640
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is json you should just be able to parse it and access `recentAveragePrice`:

```
import json
sample_string = '''{"assetStock":null,"sales":250694,"numberRemaining":null,"recentAveragePrice":731,"originalPrice":null,"priceDataPoints":[{"value":661,"date":"2022-08-11T05:00:00Z"},{"value":592,"date":"2022-08-10T05:00:00Z"},{"value":443,"date":"2022-08-09T05:00:00Z"}],"volumeDataPoints":[{"value":155,"date":"2022-08-11T05:00:00Z"},{"value":4595,"date":"2022-08-10T05:00:00Z"},{"value":12675,"date":"2022-08-09T05:00:00Z"},{"value":22179,"date":"2022-08-08T05:00:00Z"},{"value":15181,"date":"2022-08-07T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14541,"date":"2022-08-06T05:00:00Z"},{"value":15310,"date":"2022-08-05T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14146,"date":"2022-08-04T05:00:00Z"},{"value":13083,"date":"2022-08-03T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14460,"date":"2022-08-02T05:00:00Z"},{"value":16809,"date":"2022-08-01T05:00:00Z"},{"value":17571,"date":"2022-07-31T05:00:00Z"},{"value":23907,"date":"2022-07-30T05:00:00Z"},{"value":39007,"date":"2022-07-29T05:00:00Z"},{"value":38823,"date":"2022-07-28T05:00:00Z"}]}'''

data = json.loads(sample_string)
recent_price = data['recentAveragePrice']
print(recent_price)
```

outputs:

```
731
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in a popular format called [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). It's commonly used to exchange data between different systems like a server and a client, or a Python program and JavaScript program.

Now Python doesn't use JSON per-se, but it has a data type called a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that behaves very similarly to JSON. You can access elements of a dictionary as simply as:

```py
print(my_dictionary["recentAveragePrice"])
```

Python has a built-in library meant specifically to handle JSON data, and it includes a function called [`loads()`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) that can convert a string into a Python dictionary. We'll use that.

Finally, putting all that together, here is a more robust program to help parse your string and pick out the data you need. Dictionaries can do a lot more cool stuff, so make sure you take a look at the links above.

```py
# import the JSON library
# specifically, we import the `loads()` function, which will convert a JSON string into a Python object
from json import loads

# let's store your string in a variable
original_string = """
{"assetStock":null,"sales":250694,"numberRemaining":null,"recentAveragePrice":731,"originalPrice":null,"priceDataPoints":[{"value":661,"date":"2022-08-11T05:00:00Z"},{"value":592,"date":"2022-08-10T05:00:00Z"},{"value":443,"date":"2022-08-09T05:00:00Z"}],"volumeDataPoints":[{"value":155,"date":"2022-08-11T05:00:00Z"},{"value":4595,"date":"2022-08-10T05:00:00Z"},{"value":12675,"date":"2022-08-09T05:00:00Z"},{"value":22179,"date":"2022-08-08T05:00:00Z"},{"value":15181,"date":"2022-08-07T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14541,"date":"2022-08-06T05:00:00Z"},{"value":15310,"date":"2022-08-05T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14146,"date":"2022-08-04T05:00:00Z"},{"value":13083,"date":"2022-08-03T05:00:00Z"},{"value":14460,"date":"2022-08-02T05:00:00Z"},{"value":16809,"date":"2022-08-01T05:00:00Z"},{"value":17571,"date":"2022-07-31T05:00:00Z"},{"value":23907,"date":"2022-07-30T05:00:00Z"},{"value":39007,"date":"2022-07-29T05:00:00Z"},{"value":38823,"date":"2022-07-28T05:00:00Z"}]}
"""

# convert the string into a dictionary object
dictionary_object = loads(original_string)

# access the element you need
print(dictionary_object["recentAveragePrice"])
```

Output upon running this program:

```bash
$ python exp.py 
731
```